# BitLocker Setup requires the drive file system to be NTFS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell-poweredge, bitlocker

We are running a new Windows 2008 R2 Server on Dell PowerEdge R620 Hardware.

I am trying to enable BitLocker Encryption on the C Drive, I have already enabled the TPM from the BIOS.

During the phase where it checks your computers configuration, we get an error that says

"BitLocker Setup requires the drive file system to be NTFS. Convert the file system and run BitLocker Setup again. "

The C Drive is in fact NTFS, but we have noticed that there are a couple extra partitions that were added automatically by Dell, mainly a 39 MB OEM partition, and a 2GB Partition Marked "OS" that is FAT32.

I am wondering if anybody has experienced a similar scenario, as I am trying to figure out how to proceed forward at this point? Ideally I would like to keep any of the Dell partitions if it means we have utilities available to troubleshoot the hardware if it ever has a problem.

Any insight on this configuration issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are right in your assumption that the Error you get is in case because you have that DELL OEM Partition with the FAT32 FS. If you want to turn on BitLocker, backup that partition, delte it, turn on BitLocker and restore the Partition if you really need it. I have not found another way yet to get around that issue.

After the deletion of the Recovery-Partition the BitLocker-Check will not fail anymore.

Comment: Even with the 100MB system partition at the start of the drive that Windows 7 creates this is still an issue? @riscie

Comment: the Windows system partition is ntfs and not a problem for bitlocker.

Comment: As @longneck points out, the boot partition is not a problem and works fine with BitLocker

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you delete the dell OEM partition.  As Riscie mentioned, this only contains Dell tools. This tools can be easily redownloaded dell support website as an ISO and boot from it if you need to